# Uploading a video to a Lemoon file store

Tags: lemoon

I'm trying to upload a small (2MB) video in mp4 format to my file store in Lemoon so I can include it in a blog post. I have tried in IE11 and Chrome and in both cases it goes through the motions and looks like it's uploading (I get the progress bar and it runs to completion) but I never get a file in the store. Any ideas why not?

Comment: What does the log say (in [root]\app_data\logs\lemoon.log)? Can you still upload other files? And are you using the WYSIWYG-editor to upload it (Insert/Edit file -> Upload), or the Files-section (Files -> Upload files)?

Comment: Log says "ERROR|Mindroute.Lemoon.Web.LemoonModule|System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Request timed out." I can upload other files. I'm using Files > Upload files.

Comment: What do you have as vaules in your [root]\admin\web.config file under maxRequestLength and maxAllowedContentLength?